# How to use a table reference as a variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I been doing a sheet to resume my statistics for every month, and i got a problem with the table that was supposed to import the values of each day of a month in the table varying for the month that is "selected".

I got 12 sheets that each one has 31 days to complete manually. The resume needs to catch the info for each day on the specified table.

So i got the tables in every sheet defined with `janWeight`, `fevWeight`, `marWeight` And goes on. In the resume i have a table that verify the Insert in a specific cell that define the month that i am looking for. 
I need a formula that can do the reference to the specified table. Like if the cell for the month is "3" i'am looking for the table `marWeight`, and them i can do the import of all the information.

I really can pass thru this problem importing every single value of the sheets by copying them using `=COUNTIF()` but this would generate a table with 2,232‬ cells, and that's not worth at all.

Thanks.

Comment: We can provide much more help if you can supply some sample data and show the formulas you've tried so far.

Comment: I alredy did testing with INDIRECT and creating a hidden table that import everything at once.
But i really dont have any idea to how do something like this, i tried to =VLOOKUP but i dont know how to use the table(month) as a variable.

Comment: i could use =VLOOKUP(Value1, Variable that refeer to the specified sheet, index etc...
But, how?

Comment: If you provide some data, we can see what you may need

Comment: I need to control the weight of breads that i produce. i write them on the sheets, i got 12 of them, one for each has a lot of tables that calculate other things, the table that calculate the weight of bread and its set like this:
Titles are the name of each type of bread, and the lines are the days.
and its manually assigned in grams.

In the main sheet that i look for the resume present me just like the inserts, but it has to automatically update the values according to the month that its write in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of vba codes that work alongside of objects such as tables. Since they're named I'll give some basic calls, but [you can read more about Table and VBA here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) This source has helped me teach myself VBA and I found it very helpful.

You can change the sheet from Activesheet to a specific one if it better suits your code.

`Table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("janWeight").ListColumns("Column 1").Index` Would be how you reference the column named "Column 1" in your data for example. It works from the name, but you can change this as well to be the actual column number rather than a name. Just make sure to declare variables correctly as well.